# Selection sort didn't sort in descending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selection-sort

Here is my homework: I want to know how many compares and exchanges take place in selection sort. When I declared my array in reverse or in descending order like this:

```
int arr[] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
```

…it's running fine and count compares and exchanges too but when I try to give 'n' and filled array in reverse order, it filled it in descending order but it didn't work properly to sort in descending order to count my exchanges although it count compares.

Here is the code:

```
public class SelectionSort {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int compares = 0, exchanges = 0, x;
        x = in.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int [x];
        int n = arr.length;
        int s = 0;
        int min;
        int temp, i, j;
        System.out.print("Filling Array");
        for(i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            arr[i] = i;
            System.out.print(" " + arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for(i = 0; i < n ; i++)
        {
            min = i ;

            for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                compares++;
                if(arr[min] > arr[j])
                    min = j;
            }

            if(min != i)
            {
                exchanges++;
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[min];
                arr[min] = temp;
            }

            System.out.println("Iteration " + (++s));
            for(int a = 0; a < arr.length; a++)
                System.out.print(" " + arr[a]);

            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Compares -- >> " + compares);
        System.out.println("Exchanges -->> " + exchanges);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give some samples of what compares and exchanges are expected vs what your program gives for a given array?

Comment: If i run your code and input 4 it prints:
`Filling Array 3 2 1`
`Iteration 1`
 `0 1 2 3`
`Iteration 2`
 `0 1 2 3`
`Iteration 3`
 `0 1 2 3`
`Iteration 4`
 `0 1 2 3`

`Compares -- >> 6`
`Exchanges -->> 0` Not sure what you expect it to be.

Comment: For suppose i have a array {2,1,3,4} , Now functions checks each elements if its greater then next then swap so exchange++ , in this array only one exchange is occur while 6 compares for finding small and large

Comment: "Now functions checks each elements" , the problem with this is that i don't see any functions in your code exept the `main` function aka method.

Comment: @WonderWorld See you filled array in reverse order and its running iteration in ascending order , so if your array in ascending only compares is increament not any exchange takes place

Comment: yes i just made my code in main instead of making another class or new function

Comment: Clean up spelling, grammar, whitespace in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple reason for this to show the wrong count of `EXCHANGES` that take place. If you follow the code here:

```
System.out.print("Filling Array");
for(i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    arr[i] = i;
    System.out.print(" " + arr[i]);
}
```

Got it yet? The array is never filled or sorted in descending order, you are only printing it in reversed order.

Let's suppose `n = 3` and when the array is initialized it's `{ 0, 0, ... }` and follow the loop:

**Iteration 1:**

```
// i = n - 1 = 2
// i > 0 = true
// arr[i] = i;
// arr[2] = 2;
// print statement
```

**Iteration 2:**

```
// i - 1 = 1
// i > 0 = true
// arr[i] = i;
// arr[1] = 1;
// print statement
```

**Iteration 3:**

```
// i - 1 = 0
// i > 0 = false
// arr = { 0, 1, 2 }
```

Try this for a filling a reverse sorted array:

```
for (i = n - 1, z = 0; i > 0; i--, z++)
{
    arr[z] = i;
}
```